# Evaluation of user existence occurs before login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my Register `HttpPost` method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                string ret=WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);

                if (WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {}
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }            
        return View(model);
    }
```

No matter whatever username I register with I always get an exception stating that "The name is already in use. Please choose another user name". The error occurs at line `string ret=WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);` it adds username and password into my DBtable but throws an exception right after that.

[**Update**]
My `RegisterModel` looks like this

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Remote("IsUserAvailable", "UserExistsValidation")]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    [StringLength(30,MinimumLength=2)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

and `IsUserAvailable` method of `UserExistsValidationControler`

```
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public class UserExistsValidationControler: Controller
{
    public JsonResult IsUserAvailable(string username)
    {
        if (!WebSecurity.UserExists(username))
        {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        string suggestedUsername = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "'{0}' is not available", username);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            string candidate = username + i.ToString();
            if (!WebSecurity.UserExists(candidate))
            {
                suggestedUsername = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "'{0}' is not available. Try {1}.", username, candidate);
                break;
            }
        }
        return Json(suggestedUsername, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even after I add that line I still get the same error message but the new username and password are already added into the table

Answer (score 1):

`WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount` do the following:

```
this.CreateUserRow(database, userName, values);
this.CreateAccount(userName, password, requireConfirmation);
```

2 operations are not in transaction, that's why you ended up with the record in user profile table.
On `CreateAccount()` there is a check at the beginning, this is how [msdn describes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.createaccount%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) it:

> When you call this method, the membership system verifies that a user
>   profile record exists that matches the name that you pass in username.
>   (The method queries the table that you specified in the userTableName
>   parameter and the column specified in the userNameColumn column when
>   you called the InitializeDatabaseConnection() method in order to
>   initialize membership.) It then creates a new entry in the membership
>   table, using the user ID of the corresponding record in the user
>   profile table.

There is a possibility, that you have a problem in your connection settings, therefore it's better to start from checking your settings.